# How to encode a list of integers, how to find an arithmetical formula for a sequence?

Tags: computer-science, computer-arithmetic

I have the following list of integers :
$$t={0, 15, 73, 27, 73, 105, 25, 65, 26, 8, 84, 72, 15, 73, 27, 73, 105, 25, 65}$$
And I want to find a function or (an expression) such that $f(k)$ is always the $k$-th element in the sequence, for example $f(k)=15k$  gives me the first two element and if I added $f(k)=15k(k-1)+73$ gives me the first three elements. I can follow this method it gives me a very big expression at the end.

Is there a way to find a very simple function to do this?: any expression is allowed boolean operations, arithmetic operations, ...

**Edit** As proposed in the comments we can restrict to the sequence $$15, 73, 27, 73, 105, 25, 65, 26, 8, 84, 72$$
I found an interesting function in Mathematica [FindSequenceFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) but it does not produce anything for this sequence .

If someone could find two integers $a,b$ such that $f(k)= a\mod(b+k)$ then it's exactly what I'm looking for

Thank you,

Comment: Well you could always generate a Lagrange polynomial. That would be quite messy though so most probably not what you're looking for unfortunately.

Comment: It's periodic other than the initial $0$...does that continue?

Comment: If I were you I would use some polynomial regression. It would fit with round operation. How many terms you will have I cannot say. One needs to check

Comment: I would say $f(0)=0$, then for $n>0$ $f(n)=f(n\; mod(11))$ with $f(\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}=\{15,73,27,73,105,25,65,26,8,84,72\}$   Simple look up, other than taking the remainder on division by $11$.

Comment: @Elaqqad: Do you care if it an interpolating polynomial, mod functions, unitstep functions?

Comment: time for you to learn the discrete Fourier transform and the Fourier series

Comment: @Moo no any function is acceptable just to relatively small expression

Comment: Maybe try braking the numbers into factors, for exapmple, 2,3,5,7,13,73 and try to find polynomials as their degrees?

Comment: For a finite list of non-negative you can always find constants $A,B\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(k)=A\bmod {(B+k)}$ works (where $x\bmod y$ denotes the unique integer $z\in\{0,1,\ldots,y-1\}$ such that $y$ divides $x-z$). However, while the expression is simple, the numbers $A,B$ may become quite large ...

Comment: @lulu yes it's periodic

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I tried to find $a$ and $b$^but it took me a lot of time on my computer and no entries found for $a,b\leq 10^4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inexpensive pairing function $(a, b)\mapsto \langle a,b\rangle$, for example
$$
\langle a,b\rangle := \frac {(a+b)(a+b+1)} 2 + a,
$$
(this is the Cantor [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)) and encode a sequence $(s_0, \dotsc s_n)$ by $\langle k, \langle s_0, \langle \dotsc \langle s_{n-1,}s_n\rangle\dotsc\rangle\rangle$. This encodes a sequence as the iteratively/recursively paired elements, tagged with the sequence length. Thus,
$$\begin{align}
(a) &\mapsto \langle 1, n \rangle \\
(a,b) &\mapsto \langle 2, \langle a,b\rangle \rangle \\
(a,b,c) &\mapsto \langle 3, \langle a,\langle b,c\rangle \rangle\rangle \\
&\,\vdots\\
\end{align}$$

The downside of this approach is that arbitrary indexing becomes relatively expensive, as the nesting has to be undone — it's more expensive to retrieve the $i$-th element for larger indexes $i$ than for smaller $i$. Before indexing a lot into a sequence number (a number regarded as encoding a sequence), you'd probably want to first convert it back to a sequence (/list/tuple...). Depending on the details of your actual problem, this may be an option, or it may make the whole approach pointless.

---

The wikipedia article on pairing functions cited above derives the inverses of $\langle a,b \rangle$. Here's the result: If $n = \langle a,b \rangle$, then $a, b$ can be recovered from $n$ as follows:

Let 
$$\begin{align}
w &= \big\lfloor \frac {\sqrt {8n+1} - 1} 2 \big\rfloor, \tag{$w = a+b$} \\
t &= \frac {w (w+1)} 2; \tag{$n = t+b$} \\
\end{align}$$
then
$$\begin{align}
b &= n - t \\
a &= w - b
\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks for your answer but what I'm looking for is how to produce a function from a list not to encode any sequence of integers and I 'am very interested in the sequence in the question( Of course your answer is useful for encoding sequences at any order and there is one question how to compute the inverse of the encoded volue )

Comment: I added a reference and a note on how to compute the inverses.

Comment: thank you that was helpful

Comment: Good, you're welcome & thank you. So, not bad performance: computing the inverses is $O(1)$, and converting a sequence number back to a list is $O(n)$, $n$ = list length. Furthermore, sequence numbers don't get ridiculously big compared to sizes of list elements, unlike other encodings (powers of primes, for example).